# useEffect console logs multi times

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have here the following `useEffect` that querying data from firestore.

Since the sessionData logs multiple times, is this logs are the query executing multi times or the useEffect render multiple times?

```
const [sessionData, setSessionData] = useState([]);
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {            
      try {             
        const sessionsUnsub = onSnapshot( 
          query( collection( db, `users/${uidRef}/business/${businessID}/branches/${currentSelectedBranchID}/sessions` ),
            orderBy("isActive", "desc"),
            //orderBy("startDate", "asc")
            orderBy("endDate", "desc")
          ),
          (querySnapshot) => {
            const sessions = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
              return {
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id,
              };
            })

            setSessionData(sessions)
            setIsloading(false)            
                        
          }
        );
        return sessionsUnsub;
      
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }      
    }
    
  }, [user, businessID, currentSelectedBranchID, uidRef]);
```

I expect to know if this `useEffect` renders the page multi times or it execute the query multiple times?

Comment: While you can pass a simple callback as the second argument, you really should pass in `{ next: (snapshot) => {}, error: (err) => {} }` instead. You should also skip sending the query if `businessID`, `currentSelectedBranchID`, or `uidRef` are missing (because the query would fail anyway). I'd also use `if (!user) return; // cancelled` at the top of the useEffect callback so you don't have to indent the entire thing

Answer (score 0):

If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

Doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Everytime that updated: [user, businessID, currentSelectedBranchID, uidRef], useEffect render changes.